# how to skip Google recaptcha by trust ip

Tags: recaptcha

I'm using google recaptcha V2

Is there any way to set trust IPs - ips that will not require to check the "i'm not rebot" checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a client side validation of the `trusted IPs` it would break the whole point in having captcha since the function may be overridden.

If you are serving the form from your server and if it is server-side rendered, things may be easy and you could avoid using captcha by modifying the form appropriately in your server. The exact code may vary based on your stack.

If you want to implement this using some other REST service, you can employ multiple strategies. One could be to request a token from your service and based on the IP whitelist you generate and send a new token which can be used to replace the captcha in the front end. But in this case, you must do an extra validation to check if the token is valid and from the same IP as the one requested.

In any case, I am not sure if there is a straight forward mechanism that would give you the same level of security as a Captcha that sets trusted IPs without some server side magic.